# Google OAuth2 Client for brand accounts OR how to upload photos to a Google Photo brand account

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-account

With a normal Google Account (with email) is it possible to access the Google Data Client with a pre-fetched access-token.

```
gd_client = gdata.photos.service.PhotosService(source=user_agent, email=email, additional_headers={'Authorization' : 'Bearer %s' % credentials.access_token})
```

But, how is this done with so-called brand-accounts? How do I get authenticated to the right brand-account?

Answer (score 2):

I will answer my own question here. When logged in into https://myaccount.google.com/, you can switch to your brand account by clicking your account icon on the top right and select the specific brand account.

On the left side, click on "Personal Data" or similar (Persönliche Daten in German). You will see the brand account email there with which you can login.